# How to use Public plugin methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was playing with this code (https://github.com/rendro/countdown) and I was wondering how I should use "Public plugin methods" (as listed in the readme.md).

Specifically, I am launching a countdown timer like this:

```
function Timer(minutes) {
$('.countdown').countdown({
            date: new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 60 * minutes - 1000),
            render: function(data) {
            $(this.el).text(this.leadingZeros(data.min) + ":" + this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2));
});
}

// Launch timer
Timer(2);
```

And now I am trying to use the "stop()" method, but can't figure out how I should be doing it.

I tried `$('.countdown').countdown.sop()`, then I tried `countdown.stop()`, then I tried using `var timer = Timer(2)` followed by `timer.stop()`

I just don't know how I should be using these methods.

Any help greatly appreciated, as the repo is inactive now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it bind object to element by data. if you want to stop it, please first get the object and then stop, like below code:

```
$('.countdown').data('countdown').stop();
```

Comment: Oh well ! That was easy. I get the concept now. Thanks !